# Restoring Local Git Repository from Remote Copy Without Affecting Working Directory

Tags: linux, git

I have a local Git repository that I keep a backup copy of as follows:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git clone --bare /path/to/repo_backup/my_repo.git
cd /path/to/repo_backup/my_repo.git
git init --bare --shared
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add origin /path/to/repo_backup/my_repo.git
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

While I was out for two weeks, our IT department unilaterally decided to delete the **.git** directory that was my local repo. Changes were then made to the working directory, and I am unable to run **git status** to see what changes were made.

I need to restore the local repo from the backup (i.e. remote) repo **without affecting the working directory** (i.e. so I can't do a straight **git clone**).

I have attempted this via:

```
cp /path/to/repo_backup/my_repo.git /path/to/local/repo/.git
cd /path/to/local/repo
```

However when I run **git status**, I get this error:

```
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

How may I properly restore the local repo without affecting the working directory?

Comment: There’s `git clone --no-checkout`, by the way. You could then use `git symbolic-ref` to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cp` command you've shown lacks the `-r` flag, so I'd expect it to fail to copy the `.git` directory.

Could it be that you copied your new `.git` directory *into* the old .git directory, rather than to replace the old one? (That is to say, to accidentally create a `.git/.git` subdirectory)

Perhaps try:

```
mv /path/to/local/repo/.git /path/to/local/repo/TEMP-old-dot-git
cp -r /path/to/repo_backup/my_repo.git /path/to/local/repo/.git
```

Also, although we can convert between bare and non-bare repos simply by renaming, doing so relies on git internals, and it's possible git won't always work this way. [Wise git users recommend](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_make_existing_non-bare_repository_bare.3F) using `git clone` rather than renaming.

> I can't do a straight git clone

You could if you cloned into a temporary directory and then moved the .git directory. The clone operation itself will refuse to collide with existing files anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of -r switch in cp command is likely culprit.
Regarding impossibility of git clone to restore local copy - you could do it by:

1. git clone "remote" backup to a different directory
2. Move your working directory to said different directory (while overwritting all files)
3. Move whole thing back to original path

... but it doesn't make much sense if you can recover .git directory.
That said, using local git repo as a backup has it weaknesses (that you already experienced); you could consider checking [Git Backup Guide](https://xopero.com/resources/git-backup-guide/) for details on good backup practices.